# How can I launch another batch file by simply force-closing one?

Tags: java, console, launch

I want to execute a java function inside my server's source, 
so I thought of using another batch file to do that,
so my question is: how can I launch another batch file by simply closing the first one?

Thanks.

Comment: How does Java relate to your batch file?

Comment: I am running a server using that batch file, the server is in Java :P

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Can you explain your question better please? Why do you expect something to open when you stop it? What is the context?

Comment: I want to execute a java function inside my server's source, so I thought of using another batch file to do so, so my question is, how can I launch another batch file by simply closing the first one?

Comment: Mark, according to your solution, how can I call it when the batch is closed? thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with the information in the comments. If I understand your question, you want to wait for the batch file that starts up the server to end, then run another batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your batch file you can tell it to start the other one. For instance:

```
start batchfilenumber2.bat
```

If the batch file is in a different directory than the first one then just add the path of the new batch file after start:

```
start "C:\Users\xStr0nGx\Desktop\batchfilenumber2.bat"
```

The quotes are not required but good practice if you ever use a path with spaces in it.

The info below could also be helpful if the batch stays open until a certain argument is met. You could put in a goto statement:

```
@echo off
:start
echo "I'm king of the world"
```

(paraphrasing here)

```
IF "1" is pushed goto start
IF "2" is pushed goto end
:end
echo "We're done here...."
start batchfilenumber2.bat
```

Comment: Hmm, but I need that extra batch-file to launch when I close the main one.. :/

Comment: Right so here is an example:

    @echo off
    echo "I'm currently running right now, nothing can stop me"
    pause
    echo "Now I'm going to start a new process!!!"
    start batchfilenumber2.bat (or .txt or .doc or .whatever)

Now a new file is opened and the batch file closes because it met the end of it's commands.